# Best practices for associating file type with Prism application

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, prism

I am working on a huge GIS application. The project file type extension is been registered with the application by the application installer. On double click over the project file in Windows Explorer, it automatically launches the application and OnStartup event arguments are giving me the complete file path in App.xaml.cs. Now, what best practice should I use to open the project file.
I need to handle drag drop also for the same project file type. Please suggest the best practices for this implementation.

Comment: What is the project file, and what do you want to do with it in your application?

Comment: Project file is the file saved by my GIS application. User can build a GIS model and save it using File->Save As. I want to associate that file extension with my application. Double click on file in Windows Explorer should open my application with the selected model displayed.